# Why vue's method can not work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to write a method on vue, why the 'clickA' can not work, but 'clickB' workable?

Note: The solution should let the [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) function work like the 'clickB'.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    clickA: function() {
      _.throttle(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        console.log('A clicked', time)
      }, 1000)
    },
    clickB: _.throttle(function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('B clicked', time)
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="clickA">A</button>
  <button type="button" @click="clickB">B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: clickA doesn't return the function?

Comment: Not duplicate, this question is just try to figure out why the clickA can not workable in NOT classified script

Answer (score 1):

`_.throttle` **returns** a new function. Think about this, it may be a little hard to wrap your head around, but it makes sense!

`clickB` is bound to that function which `_.throttle` returns.

However, in `clickA`, you're not binding the click action to that function which `_.throttle` creates.

Answer (score 0):

`_.throttle` returns a throttled function.

So you can define a new function:

`var slowThing = _.throttle(fastThing)`

Or you can define a function as a property:

```
object: {
    slowThing: _.throttle(fastThing)
}
```

But in `clickA` above, the throttled function is isn't assigned:

```
slowThing: function() {
    // this creates a new function but doesn't execute it
    _.throttle(fastThing)
}
```